# OBEXFileTransferServices doesn't connect

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth

I'm trying to write a macOS app that would connect to already paired the bluetooth phone and retrieves the list of address book entries and call records. This information should be available via standard OBEX interface. I'm relatively new to macOS development (although have enough experience with iOS development) and I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong on a very basic level.

Here are snippets of my code:

First I'm finding particular paired Bluetooth device by its address

```
let paired = IOBluetoothDevice.pairedDevices()
let device = paired?.first(where: { (device) -> Bool in
    return (device as? IOBluetoothDevice)?.addressString == "some_address"
}) as? IOBluetoothDevice
```

This actually works fine and I'm getting back valid object. Next, I'm picking up address book service and creating BluetoothOBEXSession for it

```
let service = device!.getServiceRecord(for: IOBluetoothSDPUUID(uuid32:kBluetoothSDPUUID16ServiceClassPhonebookAccess.rawValue))
let obexSession = IOBluetoothOBEXSession(sdpServiceRecord: service!)
```

This also works fine, I'm getting proper service object and session is created. 
Next step (I would assume) is to create an OBEXFileTransfer session and do something (like checking current directory or retrieving the content of `telecom/cch` which supposed to have the list of combined outgoing and incoming calls:

```
let ftp = OBEXFileTransferServices(obexSession: obexSession!)
ftp!.delegate = self

if ftp!.connectToFTPService() == 0 {
     NSLog("\(ftp!.currentPath())") // -- empty
     ftp!.changeCurrentFolderForward(toPath: "telecom/cch")
     NSLog("\(ftp!.currentPath())") // -- empty
     ftp!.retrieveFolderListing()
}
```

I have added the following delegate's method to my view controller (to receive callbacks from OBEX FTS but they never get called:

```
override func fileTransferServicesRetrieveFolderListingComplete(_ inServices: OBEXFileTransferServices!, error inError: OBEXError, listing inListing: [Any]!) {
    NSLog("Listing complete...")
}

override func fileTransferServicesConnectionComplete(_ inServices: OBEXFileTransferServices!, error inError: OBEXError) {
    NSLog("Connection complete...")

}

override func fileTransferServicesDisconnectionComplete(_ inServices: OBEXFileTransferServices!, error inError: OBEXError) {
    NSLog("Disconnect complete...")
}

override func fileTransferServicesAbortComplete(_ inServices: OBEXFileTransferServices!, error inError: OBEXError) {
    NSLog("Abort complete...")
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I also could not find any good Bluetooth examples for macOS either, if somebody has good links, please do share.